# replace value of a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to replace the name of the month in an NSString with that of its two digit numerical value, e.g. "January"=>"01", "February"=>"02". The approach I am using is as follows:

```
if (mois==@"january") { mois=@"01";}   
if (mois==@"February") { mois=@"02";}
```

...but it is not working. How do I go about making this replacement?

Comment: Ah, good point. Looking at all the suggested answers you've not said what is not working - is it that the if statement is not working, or that the reassignment of mois is not working

Comment: Best way is to create enum for months:

  enum{
  january = 1,
  february = 2, 
  ..
  ..
  december = 12}months;

Use [this](http://make-smart-iphone-apps.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-use-enums-in-objective-c.html) link to how to use in code

Comment: @Safecase why is that the "best way"? What benefits can be gained from doing that?

Comment: he is using months to constant value

Comment: you are comparing pointers. use isEqualToString:.

Comment: @Safecase So, explain why using an enum is the "best way"? Why is that better than anything else. We are here to help and to help we should explain WHY something is "best" rather than just stating it otherwise whoever asks the questions won't be able to apply that understanding in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
if ([mois isEqualToString:@"january"]) { mois=@"01";}   
if ([mois isEqualToString:@"February"]) { mois=@"02";}
```

Answer (score 7):

`if ([mois isEqualToString:@"january"])` is what you are looking for.

What you are doing is comparing pointers and not the values stored in them, which is why several classes in Objective-C have these `isEqualTo:` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `[mois isEqualToString:@"january"]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date functions provided by iOS. Look at NSDate and NSDateFormatter

By using the date functions, you can get the SDK to convert the month name to the month code. This will also mean you won't have to worry about if the month is in a different language or if the case is different, or if it has "Jan" instead of "January", etc.

Answer (score 0):

NSString is an object for that reason you can't use mois==@"january". You have to use 
the method isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString.

Nicola.

Answer (score -1):

NSStrings are immutable aren't they? I think you'd either have to use an NSMutableString, or use mois=[NSString stringWithString:@"01"];

Hope this helps, Nathan

Comment: Why the down vote? Whilst I'm happy to be wrong, it would be nice to know why

Comment: The string isn't being altered, just the pointer that is stored in mois is being changed. mois points to a location in memory that contains "February" and then mois is told to point to a location in memory that contains "02". The string isn't changing, it's just the pointer in mois.